# Are JavaScript use both Heap and Stack for Object type

Tags: javascript, stack, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, boxing

If I declare var `number1 = new Number(6);` will javascript use both heap and stack to store it in the memory. Is it possible to convert this number1 object to primitive type like
`var number1 = 6;` if so, then will this action delete the reference of the object from heap, and will there be an impact on memory?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really have the distinction between stack and heap allocation.

Comment: Boxing is unrelated to stack versus heap.

Comment: Well, I got pretty confused, In c++ we use a pointer to hold the reference of the memory address of an object but when we declare a variable it store it in the memory which is directly accessible. If there is no distinction between stack and heap then is a declaration (primitive type and box type) in javascript are reference type, maybe it's dumb question :)

Comment: JavaScript is a higher level language than C++ and it has a specification but how that is implemented is not specified, the engine is a black box. Unlike C++ you can't say what is really going on, apart from an implementation such as V8.